# Use SortableJS with tree structure table

Tags: sortablejs

I have tree structure like table.
Is there any way how to use nested sortable in this case?
Or in this structure it's impossible?

Thanks a lot!

```
https://jsbin.com/geqonosaqa/edit?js,output
```

```
<tbody id="groups">
                <tr data-id="60827" class="even">
                    <td style="padding-left:15px; cursor:pointer;">Matthew</td>
                    <td style="padding-left:15px; cursor:pointer;">Meyers</td>
                    <td style="15">CEO 0</td>
                    <td>Jan. 15, 2024</td>
                </tr>
                <tr data-id="60867" class="odd">
                    <td style="padding-left:30px; cursor:pointer;">Patricia</td>
                    <td style="padding-left:30px; cursor:pointer;">Schultz</td>
                    <td style="30">Deputy CEO 0</td>
                    <td>Jan. 15, 2024</td>
                </tr>
                <tr data-id="61028" class="even">
                    <td style="padding-left:45px; cursor:pointer;">Patricia</td>
                    <td style="padding-left:45px; cursor:pointer;">Smith</td>
                    <td style="45">Head Of Department 39</td>
                    <td>Jan. 15, 2024</td>
                </tr>
                <tr data-id="68868" class="odd">
                    <td style="padding-left:60px; cursor:pointer;">Linda</td>
                    <td style="padding-left:60px; cursor:pointer;">Moore</td>
                    <td style="60">Deputy HOD 199</td>
                    <td>Jan. 15, 2024</td>
                </tr>

            </tbody>
```

```
var el = document.getElementById('groups');
var sortable = Sortable.create(el);
```